# Flowtype spread operator not working

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Here is a link to the FLOW bin with a working version that still doesn't seem to work. A function is getting an undefined param that should be passed in using the spread operator. The error I am talking about is #78 when you open the link.

--> [Flow Bin](https://flow.org/try/#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-keoaWKAZC7iEbC4ECNZKJK-DYABZ7AaB5pLkCNifioGxNkQ0CQIU1a4DoKDnjB2G4VGl5fEQN53mM1ZsuRlHXlItGbkYCRCP8hHEWhSiFkoTHUSxUr-nIi71nkwEYG2HbYEIoDeoYj4VqGUEHqANj8aAjArvs-5qehoAgKAgmsaAxHKKAkBmhQKC7qAY54vO3CwKAIhhlQNCCPGAC0j6GchWFiaZUrAScODnO4lw1MBDryd6BFEe4UaASRMGBfgcBjioCw4OoS7Vv8UFgtBpHmZA-7hdgkXRQIACE0iyCoIj5AZZUwYwuBlCo-6Ge1AA8QgoHiIHQG2AByJBoEQ0h0EY7g+WQ-hwFkxgLUt+RaLgPlBEk+x0KCfXtaA-U6AALIdx3HXIVU1VcRC+ldpH9cA52XU9L1DXi73tbxZWPTBWlKJ13W9QNj6jRNU0zXQj50KAu6sdIcghYKXFJRRnzMWWrFAt6P1ladABMoIjtlL06CTR1KP1Y1GDhoIdBJBQvXTDPUydcZiOIKA4UIHOTGNUWTdNs2PotYHUNALBPaAKjQ7NdYNjLT2gTue64LNCT0rgKtXcWivM3rZXAATz1s9AoKBjJnb6KzJD05bHP9VzEi89A-OywOwsK7DUgS+aUvG+18ui3Q0lRbJQjB2VauzvOmt0NrWQx6RBvhzbcmp0ZZswXIWUJLl2D5RBRUAwNye4AL3B8DDApzNngtQ2HRhZNkKiN6A1rwrNZMJJ3Q2XCUwjI3F4aNVZ-hsqAAD89CDw75jR6Ahh0HQ5cm7nL2PgTf2+v2X74PWGAACLEdJuC6JoKlhrIg8X7or6lSD2A9epTYpmmmb7CkHEtLZu5JyMGCDgdw-xkypgSN-bAwF77BF0HvH0yAMrDlHOOKQ1ZGDxhvP8MSj5V4FxUDeeG3ogT-D7kQqQ2547mjQuwTg+A1iQEyNAfAyE5wUH+M1fIwFj5n3cA-HQ18zxkIoTeNCQA)

[image]I cannot seem to make the spread operator work with Flow. Am I doing something wrong here? Im using the latest version of Webstorm and "flow-bin": "^0.48.0". Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks

```
type Actions = {
  authenticateUser: (formProps: RegisterUserProps) => Dispatch,
  errorMessage: string,
  handleSubmit: any,
  valid: boolean
}

type Props = {
  ...Actions
}
```

This code just makes my IDE think there is nothing being passed into Props - so I get errors for each of the types in Actions.

Comment: Works for me. Could you please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @TamasHegedus - I added a screen shot of what happens with my IDE...What IDE are you using?

Comment: Post a link to an example in http://flow.org/try that reproduces your issue. An incomplete code snippet and a screenshot of your IDE isn't enough for anyone to help you.

Comment: @SpencerBigum Sry I was wrong! I have the same syntax error in webstorm. It seems like Jetbrains has its own parser for flow and that does not know type spread yet.

Comment: @TamasHegedus - Alright - thats good and bad news ha :( Thank you for confirming. I wonder if there is a way to update Flow parser in webstorm...

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: @TamasHegedus - updated with a new Flow bin example that still has an issue.

Answer (score 4):

There's a thread here discussing the issue: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3534

You can work around this temporarily by using

```
type Props = {
  ...$Exact<Actions>
}
```

or

```
type Actions = {|
  authenticateUser: (formProps: RegisterUserProps) => Dispatch,
  errorMessage: string,
  handleSubmit: any,
  valid: boolean
|}
```

Comment: Thanks @LewisChung - I updated my Desc with a Flow Bin example. I'll try this hack fix in a little bit and see if it solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Flow spreads will be supported in upcoming WebStorm 2017.2 - see [WEB-26408](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26408)

Comment: haven't got what you mean. the issue is not related to Flow config being used, so updating it won't help

Comment: If I understand correctly, there are two issues at play in this question. One is that WebStorm cannot currently parse the type spread syntax, and the other is that Flow is not behaving as the OP expects when type spread is used.

Comment: hey @NatMote - I upgraded to webstorm 2017.2 preview - so the spread syntax works it seems like. The second issue that I linked above is the undefined error in a method on the object that is being used in the spread syntax...